# JUnit : Unit Test for abstract class in a Spring Boot app?

Tags: java, spring-boot, csv, unit-testing, junit

In my Java (Spring Boot) app, I am trying to test the following method using JUnit5 and Mockito:

```
public abstract class CsvService<T extends CsvBean> {

    public List<T> readFromCsv(Class<T> type, CsvToBeanFilter filter) {
        List<T> data = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("data/" + getFileName());
            Reader reader = new FileReader(resource.getFile());

            ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<T> strategy = 
                new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<>();
            strategy.setType(type);
            strategy.setColumnMapping(getColumns());
            
            CsvToBean<T> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder<T>(reader)                    
                    .withFilter(filter)
                    .build();

            data = getData(csvToBean);
            reader.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            log.error(FILE_READ_ERROR, ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return data;
    }

    protected abstract String getFileName();

    protected abstract String[] getColumns();

    protected abstract List<T> getData(CsvToBean<T> csvToBean);
}
```

I already wrote Unit Test for the method implementations of the abstract methods (`getData()`, etc.), but I also want to write Unit Test for this `readFromCsv()` method.

```
@Service
public class AirportService extends CsvService<Airport> {

    // code omitted

    @Override
    protected List<Airport> getData(CsvToBean<Airport> csvToBean) {
        List<Airport> airports = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Airport bean : csvToBean) {
            Airport airport = new Airport(
                    bean.getId()
            );
            airports.add(airport);
        }
        return airports;
    }
}
```

Here is my Unit Test:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class CsvServiceTest {

    private CsvService service;

    @Mock
    private AirportService airportService;

    @Mock
    private CsvToBean<Airport> csvToBean;

    @Mock
    private CsvToBeanFilter filter;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        service = new AirportService();
    }


    @Test
    void test() {
        csvToBean.setFilter(filter);

        Airport airport = new Airport(101, "DK");
        when(filter.allowLine((String[]) any())).thenReturn(true);
        when(csvToBean.iterator())
            .thenReturn(new ArrayIterator<>(new Airport[]{airport}));

        List<Airport> result = service.readFromCsv(Airport.class, filter);
        
        // assertions
    }
}
```

But the test is always read the CSV file as it retrieved via `getFileName()` method (the file in the project). But I want to mock it and read the provided airport data via stub. So, how can I make this unit test properly testing this CSV reader method?

Comment: An abstract class on its own is neither instantiable nor testworthy. We normally have implementations of that abstract class. We can test them (and thus also test the implementation of the abstract class).

Comment: No, `getData()`, `getFileName()` and `getColumns()` methods have their implementation in another services and I wrote Unit Tests for those services. But `readFromCsv()` method is not abstract and I think I need to write Unit Test for that method. So, how can I write test for this method?

Comment: @Turing85 In here, I used Template Method Design pattern and there is no implementation for `readFromCsv()` and the implementation is already in this class. I agree with you and I do not write Unit Test for the abstract methods (I already wrote for its implementations). So, I think I should write Unit Test for this method, right?

Comment: Looking at the implementation, it is hard-wired to read content from a file. There are ways to mock - for example - a constructor call and return a mock for `new ClassPathResource("data/" + getFileName())`, but I would not recommend doing this. Instead, I would recommend creating different files for different test cases, thus testing with different (known) file contents.

Comment: Thanks for help, but I could not understand what you mean. Could you add an example as an answer for the most proper way for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either (1) create a `Spy` instead of the `AirportService` and mock the `getFileName()` method:

```
service = Mockito.spy(new AirportService());
```

and then mock the desired method:

```
Mockito.doReturn((/* your value */)).when(service).getFileName();
```

or (2) create yet another class, this time extending the `AirportService`; there you can implement the `getFileName` so it returns your mock file name.